# Laravel 5.4: Password reset token not the same as email token

Tags: laravel

I have a slight problem after upgrading to laravel 5.4

When i do a password reset, the email gets generated and sent perfectly, however the token it saves to the user record in the database is as follows:

```
$2y$10$N0WFuqEkEIFto.CazxYLdOUmY1X9tBHfvDn8iWKUdlq2W9uOc00Ku
```

But the token it sends to the user to do a password reset is:

```
bc1c82830bc8ad1356aa5e2a2a5a342ae6c6fabd385add503795cca1a1993e15
```

My question is why are the two tokens different. and how do i perform a check now to validate if the token exists in the database as i need to get the email address to post to the reset controller.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: did you find any solution...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Token you store in database is hashed same as your **password** column in **users** table.
However the token you recieve is not hashed. Thats why they are different

Due to get this password ;

`$2y$10$N0WFuqEkEIFto.CazxYLdOUmY1X9tBHfvDn8iWKUdlq2W9uOc00Ku`

you have to do

`Hash::make('bc1c82830bc8ad1356aa5e2a2a5a342ae6c6fabd385add503795cca1a1993e15');`

And you **cannot** revert this process backwards.

Comment: Ok sure. then how do i compare the two tokens now in 5.4 to get the linked email address to post through to the password reset controller?

Comment: vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Hashing/BcryptHasher.php

check this class there is check method

Comment: Depending on documentation on https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/hashing   you can use Hash::check() function as I have mentioned above

Comment: You should not run `Hash::make()` again to compare the hashed password with your plaintext string. This may have worked in previous versions of Laravel where the hashing library used SHA256, but in Laravel 5.4+ it uses bcrypt which does not generate the exact same string twice in a row. You should use the `Hash::check()` method for verifying it.

Comment: @Anar Bayramov i only have token how can i get hashed password from the database because i only have token.

Answer (score 3):

The token in the database is encrypted with Bcrypt. That's why it is different in the database.

The token will still work when you use it.

Comment: Sure that is totally understandable. but i need to post through the email address linked to that token to the PasswordResetController. so i need to perform a check first to the get email.

Answer (score 3):

The token it stores in the database is the same string, but hashed with bcrypt, a secure and adaptive algorithm based on the Blowfish cipher.

You can see the documentation for the vanilla PHP [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function to see how it's built, and the [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) function to verify that the hashed string is valid against an unhashed version of it (what is sent to the user, in this case).

---

### [Laravel Hashing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/hashing)

Laravel includes its own hashing objects and facades which are documented.

To create a hash:

```
$string = 'Hello world.';
$hash = Hash::make($string);
```

To verify the hash against a plain string:

```
if (Hash::check($string, $hash)) {
    // The passwords match...
}
```

---

*Note: In Laravel 5.4, the email token changed from SHA256 to bcrypt in an undocumented change (as issue [#18570](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18570) shows), so bear that in mind if you are upgrading from Laravel 5.3 or lower.*

Comment: Hi i dont have email i only have the token how can i then verify that token is valid and not expired i am using laravel 5.4.